# Drag and drop to batch file from UNC - how to capture %cd%

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
Set dd=%DATE:~0,2%
Set mm=%DATE:~3,2%
Set yyyy=%DATE:~6,4%
Set hh=%TIME:~0,2%
Set ii=%TIME:~3,2%
Set ss=%TIME:~6,2%
Set zipFileHandle=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%-%hh%-%ii%-%ss%
Set files=%*

%~dp0\7za a -t7z %cd%\%zipFileHandle%.7z %files%
```

When I drop a group of files and/or directories on it, it compresses them into a dated .7z file in the root folder they all came from.

The problem is that if I drop network files, with a path starting with `\\`, the batch file changes the value of the save directory to `C:\Windows`.

How can I get the value of `%cd%` **before** `cmd` changes it to the system root?

If that's not possible, is it possible to get the common root folder from the variable `%files%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get next message:

```
'\\computer\path'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

So you could use next:

```
%~dp07za a -t7z %~dp1%zipFileHandle%.7z %files%
```

Note that `\` backslash could be omitted using `%~dp0` and `%~dp1` as the `~dp` modifier expands a %variable to a *Path* only including a trailing `\` backslash.

And if source folder name contains spaces, use quoted target file name rather:

```
%~dp07za a -t7z "%~dp1%zipFileHandle%.7z" %files%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `pushd %~dp1` before calling `7za`.  That temporarily maps the UNC path of the 1st dragged-and-dropped file as a network drive letter and changes directory to it.  The mapping disappears as soon as the script exists.

Additionally, 7za has [exit codes](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm) you might make use of for fault tolerance.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %%I in (
    'wmic os get localdatetime /format:list ^| find "="'
) do set "t=%%I"

set "handle=%t:~0,4%-%t:~4,2%-%t:~6,2%_%t:~8,2%-%t:~10,2%-%t:~12,2%"

pushd "%~dp1"

"%~dp0\7za" a -t7z "%handle%.7z" %* || (
    if ERRORLEVEL 2 (
        echo Zipping failed.
        pause
    ) else (
        echo Zipping completed with errors, possibly because a file is locked by another process.
        pause
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks rojo - this works, but I was happier with the solution that was just one line-change :-)